# How to listen for new records in database with Sequelize?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I have a *PostgreSQL* database with *Sequelize* ORM and I want to listen for new entries. How should I do? Should I use Sequelize `afterCreate` hook?
Can someone help me?

Comment: If you add new records using Sequelize only then you can use hooks otherwise Sequelize knows nothing about new records that appear in DB

Comment: @Anatoly, should I use afterCreate or afterSave? I added manually record on db, to see if the hooks work. Now I try to add through sequelize.

Comment: `afterCreate` is used to catch recors that you create and `afterSave` is used to catch both `create` and `update` actons, see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6/src/hooks.js#L7

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky the solution would be streaming. Either Apache Kafka.